# FFMPEG multiple commands using filter-complex

Tags: ffmpeg

I've pieced together 3 commands but my solution involves writing a number of tempory files. I would ultimately like to pipe the output of one command into the next command, without the temporary files.

Although many questions discuss filter-complex (which is how I believe results passing as inputs is accomplished), I can't seem to find an example of commands that use filter_complexs flowing into other filter_complex commands (nested filter-complex commands?). In my example, two distinct inputs are required, resulting in one output.

```
/* 
Brighten & increase saturation of original image 
Remove white shape from black background silhouette, leaving a transparent shape
Overlay black background silhouette over brightened image. Creating a focus point
*/
ffmpeg -i OrigionalImage.png -vf eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2 -c:a copy BrightenedImage.png
ffmpeg -i WhiteSilhouette.png -filter_complex "[0]split[m][a]; [a]geq='if(lt(lum(X,Y),16),255,0)',hue=s=0[al]; [m][al]alphamerge" -c:a copy TransparentSilhouette.png
ffmpeg -i BrightenedImage.png -i TransparentSilhouette.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:a copy BrightnedSilhouette.png
```

Two original inputs and final output

Origional Image
[image: OrigionalImage]

White Silhouette
[image: WhiteSilhouette]

Brightned Silhouette
[image: BrightnedSilhouette]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i OriginalImage.png -i WhiteSilhouette.png  -filter_complex "[0]eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2[img];[1]split[m][a];[a]geq='if(lt(lum(X,Y),16),255,0)',hue=s=0[al];[m][al]alphamerge[sil];[img][sil]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" BrightnedSilhouette.png
```

---

You can also just invert WhiteSilouhette to generate the alpha,

```
ffmpeg -i OriginalImage.png -i WhiteSilhouette.png  -filter_complex "[0]eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2[img];[1]split[m][a];[a]geq='255-lum(X,Y)',hue=s=0[al]; [m][al]alphamerge[sil];[img][sil]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" BrightnedSilhouette.png
```

Comment: This is perfect! (and oddly produces slightly smaller files than my 3 step process). I noticed that the [square brackets] at the end of each function appears to be a variable with the output. This makes a lot of sense and oceans away from my original thinking. Thanks again for your time and answer

Comment: Hi Gyan,
I am new to ffmpeg, 
Can you please combine these and explain a bit,

-i \(p) -i \(imgPath) -qscale 0 -filter_complex \(self.speedQuery) \(newPath)
-i \(newPath) -i \(imgPath) -qscale 0 -filter_complex [0:v]scale=\(self.frameWidth):-1[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10 \(new)
-loop 1 -i \(imURL) -i \(new) -qscale 0 -filter_complex [1:v]scale=\(self.frameWidth):-1[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1 \(new1)